# hide show table row

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code, it works perfectly by hiding or making the table row below visible. 
The problem i am having is, when i validate my form and i submit the form, the table row that is visible goes in hidding. 
it should stay visible when the checkbox is checked.
The checkbox is still checked, however, the table row goes in hidding.

I also wanted to mention, even though the table goes hiding, upon the checkbox been checked, it retains all the form fields, nothing is lost, the problem is the table going in hiding. any ideas??

any ideas why this is happening??

```
<style>
<!--
.hidden 
{
display: none;
}
.visible 
{
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var last = "";
function show(div)
{
    if (last)
    {
        document.getElementById(last).className = "hidden";
    }   
    if (div && document.getElementById(div))
    {
        document.getElementById(div).className = "visible";
        last = div;
    }
}
</javascript>

<input name="showme" value="yesshowme" type="checkbox" onClick="show(this.value);">

<tr id="yesshowme" class="hidden">
blablablablalbla
</tr>

<submit name="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: You don't need those HTML comment markers (`<!-- -->`) anymore. And the closing tag for your script block is `</script>`, not `</javascript>`. Can you show your form validation and submission code and markup?

Comment: why you don't use document.getElementById("div").style.display = "block"; OR = "none";

Comment: Your `visible` class is useless as it doesn't have any CSS rule. Just add / remove the hidden class when needed.

Comment: I am validating using php. i agree with Joel's comment below, however, i am not sure how to make it?

Comment: Then show your PHP code that builds your form.

Comment: Marcel, the problem is not the validation. it is the form retaining what was submitted so that javascript still work! I output each form fields, and i see the checkbox still checked, however, the javascript doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you click submit, the form posts itself, and since you didn't provide the form's markup, my assumption is that it posts **to** itself. Given that information, your page is likely returning to its original state before any changes were made. If you want the changes you've made retained, you'll either need to load them from whatever datasource you're posting these changes to or persist their state through use of a session or cookie. If you're making changes via ajax, you would simply need to add `onclick="myAjaxCall();return false;"` to your submit button.

Comment: i am not using ajax. just all javascript and php, and yes the form post to itself. thanks.

Comment: I also wanted to mention, even though the table goes hiding, upon the checkbox been checked, it retains all the form fields, nothing is lost, the problem is the table going in hiding. any ideas??

Comment: @Menew: Form data will be retained across your posts, but your style information (and any changes made via javascript) will be reset to defaults. I would recommend using jQuery to perform an onload check of each checkbox state, and then set the corresponding table row visibility accordingly.